# Does accelerated charged particles violate the conservation of energy?

Tags: electromagnetism, radiation

While trying to understand the Wheeler–Feynman absorber theory, I read that the motivation of the theory was to explain why accelerated charged particles doesn't violate the conservation of energy by emitting unlimited radiation (or something like that). But I don't understand how it violates the conservation of energy in the first place. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the circular deflection of a charge in a magnetic field, then the law of conservation of energy applies exactly here.

First, a moving charge is needed (or a changing magnetic field). So there is an initial energy.

Second, the deflected charge not only loses energy in the form of emitted photons. The charge slows down at the same time. So it is the kinetic energy of the charge which cyclically changes into photons.

Third, the process does not last indefinitely. The trajectory of the charge is a spiral. In its center, the charge comes to a rest after conversion into EM radiation.